# How to dispose of variables in windows close button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows forms application, where I have declared some static variables.
On the click of exit button, I have disposed of some datatable which i have declared static.

Many a times the user instead of clicking the exit button, will just exit the windows application by clicking the X button on the left corner top.

What should be done to ensure that even if the user clicks the X button, everything is disposed of properly.

Thanks

Regards

Hema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has some good descriptions of events that you can hook into to detect when a application is exiting.

[Does Application.ApplicationExit event work to be notified of exit in non-Winforms apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529867/does-application-applicationexit-event-work-to-be-notified-of-exit-in-non-winform)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a delegate function to the Closing event of the form.

```
this.Closing += this.MyForm_Closing;
```

You can also use the Closed event of the form if you'd prefer it gets called after the form is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler to dispose your variables when the form is closing.

```
private: System::Void myDialog_FormClosing(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosingEventArgs^  e) {
         // Dispose your static variables here
     }
```